# How do reduce power supply ripple?

Tags: power-supply, switching

I was given this power supply circuit, please see the image. The problem I'm having is when I connect the 10ohm load (solenoid valve), there is a large ripple when I scope the output. I have provided a few images to show you what I'm dealing with. I have tried adding different size caps in parallel with R23. Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image: Power Supply]
Image 1: The Power Supply circuit

[image: Power Supply Switch]
Image 2: Power Supply Switching circuit

[image: Pulse With No load]
Image 3: Pulse without 10ohm load

[image: With 10ohm load]
Image 4: Pulse with 10ohm load

I have other images of the different caps used, 1nF and 0.1uF. Both of these in parallel with R23 made the ripple MUCH MUCH worse!!

Thank you all

Comment: Can you edit the schematics ? It's hard to see them.

Comment: If you're trying to provide feedforward compensation, you should put a cap in parallel with R21, not R23.

Comment: I updated the images, sorry for the duplicate image can't remove it. @The Photon I will give that a try..I have also try a cap in parallel with  R13 and R182

Comment: @The Photon It's between the 2 transistors. Also, the cap in parallel with R21 didn't make it better, made more ripple, but less than the other ones(R23). I have images if you want to see them.

Answer (score 1):

The way to compensate these loops is to add a capacitor across the transistor section OR *put a capacitor R21*. This may cut your response time, but you can't have both no ripple and response without drastically changing the design.

[image]

If you do it right you'll run a spice simulation (usually I do this for people, but I'm way to lazy right now), usually you'll see a Q resonant point in the higher end of the frequency range like the picture shown below. If you do a spice simulation, make sure you simulate the inductance of any wires or large traces, or your simulation will not match the real world.

If you don't run a spice simulation, you could run an FFT on your scope data, see the point of resonance and insert a LPF pole before the resonance Q point. Compensating these loops is not intuitive because of their closed loop nature.

If you plan on using this supply over a large range of DC output values, the Q point will change for each DC value because of the transistors.

[image]

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2983401_A_Low-Dropout_Regulator_for_SoC_With_-Reduction/figures?lo=1